# How to turn the spacy span span to string in order to append the verbs extacted of spacy to the stopwords?

Tags: python, spacy

I want to append the list of verbs extracted from spacy, to my spacy stopwords list. I extracted the verbs as you will see below.
However, they seem to be `spacy.span.span` and this does not allow me to append them. Any ideas? I tried to convert them into a string but nothing happened.

```
import spacy  # the libraries i have imported so far
import textacy
import en_core_web_sm
from spacy.lang.en.stop_words import STOP_WORDS

import string

punctuations = string.punctuation
stopwords = list(STOP_WORDS)
stopwords[:10]

nlp1=spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc=nlp1(one)
sentences=list(doc.sents)
sentence=sentences[2]
patterns=[{'POS':'VERB'}] # extracting the verbs
verbs=textacy.extract.matches(doc, patterns=patterns)

for verb in verbs:
   print(verb)   # it prints all the verbs of my coprus.

#I want to achieve that. Append the extracted verbs to the list of stopwords. 

for i in verb:
    if i not in stopwords:
          stopwords.append(i) # here is the error / bug
```

I receive the following error: `spacy.span.span has no attribute str`

Any suggestion would be appreciated